# Maximum Python object which can be passed to write()

Tags: python, file, size

I am looking around the net (so far I have found [pickle](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html) ) for an explanation for what I am doing wrong

I am trying to write a very large data structure (nested dictionary/list) to file. Using the below code I discovered that the problem might be because the passed string is too large:

```
f = open('/path/to/file' , 'w')

try:
 f.write(str(dataStructure))
except:
 try:
  f.write('ABC')
 except:
  print 'Even smaller strings such as ABC did NOT print to the file'
 else:
  print 'Smaller strings such as ABC DID print to the file'
```

the `dataStructure` dictionary has a great deal of clique information, in this case, around 10,000 - 100,000 floating point values. The whole reason I am dumping everything into a single file, instead of saving in subfiles is because I want to exec a single file to load it, rather than manually load a few dozen subsets of the file.

Before I start saving each clique (each neuron has several different incoming clique files, such that for a neuron we are looking at 20 indexed files) I was wondering if the file size was actually the problem, or if the problem must be in something else.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, please post the specific exception you are getting so that we can give you more accurate help!

Comment: If you don't put a try/except around your big "make enormous string and write" block, and the block didn't work, you should get an Exception telling you why it didn't work.

Comment: Strange, my comment didn't post. Basically I forgot to print the Exception. It takes an enormous amount of effort for me to change the program. It's MPI running on a shared cluster. So best case scenario, I would get the program to run and output within 24 hours. I will try the pickle suggestion below, if that does not work, I will print the Exception. What would be the best method to output the exception, `raise Exception`?

Comment: The best method is not to catch the exceptions. Certainly, you should *never* be doing what you are doing catching all possible exceptions instead of the specific exceptions you get.

Comment: Exceptions are very annoying, AFAIK, in MPI. They never display the whole trace. Therefore, I got into the habbit of putting try statements everywhere errors would occur, and I displayed my own, more helpful, message.

Comment: @puk, I'm not familiar with MPI in python so that may be a problem. You can also look at the traceback module to see whether using the stuff in there can get you better error messages.

Comment: @WinstonEwert, I do use traceback, but multiple nodes creates really specific problems. For example, an unidentified identifier will have an error output on each node. Imagine 10 computers interlacing their exceptions! Alternatively, with a divide by zero we'd like to know which rank raised the exception

Comment: @puk, yuck! It sounds to me like MPI could use some better handling of errors. I use my own creation, "pymultinode" when I distribute over my own little cluster of computers. I took special care to make sure that errors came through in a helpful manner.

Comment: I don't think distributed programming has very much of a user base. It is very difficult to master, and is only ever used when absolutely necessary. The transmission delays present a huge bottle neck too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm gonna guess that your problem is that the string you create is too large to exist in memory. For something that big you should write it out piece by piece to the disk.

You could use pickle, json, xml or something which should handle this correctly.

Comment: thanks, I'm going to switch to pickle. hopefully that will work. It never occurred to me that it would be too large to exist in memory. I just assumed the OS would page it, or something.

Comment: @puk, I believe the are limits to the size of a single allocated block in memory.

Comment: Pickle seems to work, however, the saved file seems encrypted (there are thousands of lines with the identical string 'aF0.0097087378640778529'. I suspect this is why the file is so large (6.7 GB). Now I have to load it to see if it is saved correctly

Comment: @puk, its not a human readable format. If you want that you'll want to use json or something. You can also look at the pickle documentation to see the different formats available. Some of the other ones are more efficient.