# Fastest way to store large files in Python

Tags: python, compression, pickle

I [recently asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626848/maximum-python-object-which-can-be-passed-to-write) regarding how to save large python objects to file. I had previously run into problems converting massive Python dictionaries into string and writing them to file via `write()`. Now I am using pickle. Although it works, the files are incredibly large (> 5 GB). I have little experience in the field of such large files. I wanted to know if it would be faster, or even possible, to zip this pickle file prior to storing it to memory.

Comment: @JBernardo That's kind of like saying when your car breaks down, you can ask your parents for a ride to where you need to go and then take public transportation to get back...

Comment: Storing it to the Hard disk. I am assuming that writing >5 GB to the hard disk takes a very long time.

Comment: @Karl LOL I thought the same, if anything it would be much slower

Comment: @puk I think you missed the point. JBernardo was suggesting using an external tool to compress the data, and using native Python libraries to read the compressed data (via an interface that decompresses while reading, making the file appear to have never been compressed in the first place as far as the rest of the code is concerned). The logical oddity is that the same libraries are equally capable of writing the file with the same kind of interface, as illustrated in my and phihag's answers.

Comment: @puk To be fair, an external tool might be optimized differently. For example, one could pipe the output through pbzip2, which can compress with multiple cores (unlike Python's implementation). Since it's very likely that the actual disk transfer is the bottleneck, piping through pzip2 (or another external compressor) wouldn't help much. The beauty of using a standard compression algorithm like gzip or bzip2 is that you're free to switch between external tools and a Python program whenever you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python code would be extremely slow when it comes to implementing data serialization.
If you try to create an equivalent to Pickle in pure Python, you'll see that it will be super slow.
Fortunately the built-in modules which perform that are quite good.

Apart from `cPickle`, you will find the `marshal` module, which is a lot faster.
But it needs a real file handle (not from a file-like object).
You can `import marshal as Pickle` and see the difference.
I don't think you can make a custom serializer which is a lot faster than this...

Here's an actual (not so old) [serious benchmark of Python serializers](http://kbyanc.blogspot.com/2007/07/python-serializer-benchmarks.html)

Comment: I feel really dumb asking this, but why is 'serialization', and WOW is marshal really 100 times faster than pickle? Can I easily switch to marshal or will it require a massive overhaul

Comment: Dumping data structures into a stream is *serialization*. You can easily switch to cPickle/marshal (I thought you were using cPickle).

Comment: no i was using plain pickle (ppickle?). I just ran a simple test comparing marshal and pickle and WOW, we're talking two orders of magnitude difference.

Comment: The marshall documentation says this: "If you’re serializing and de-serializing Python objects, use the pickle module instead – the performance is comparable" https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html

Answer (score 10):

You can compress the data with [bzip2](http://docs.python.org/library/bz2.html):

```
from __future__ import with_statement # Only for Python 2.5
import bz2,json,contextlib

hugeData = {'key': {'x': 1, 'y':2}}
with contextlib.closing(bz2.BZ2File('data.json.bz2', 'wb')) as f:
  json.dump(hugeData, f)
```

Load it like this:

```
from __future__ import with_statement # Only for Python 2.5
import bz2,json,contextlib

with contextlib.closing(bz2.BZ2File('data.json.bz2', 'rb')) as f:
  hugeData = json.load(f)
```

You can also compress the data using [zlib](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html) or [gzip](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html) with pretty much the same interface. However, both zlib and gzip's compression rates will be lower than the one achieved with bzip2 (or lzma).

Comment: I am not familiar with that syntax, but I take it BZ2File zips it to memory, then I can dump it via json (or pickle I am assuming)

Comment: @puk With what syntax? The `with` statement is just syntactic sugar that ensures the file is closed. You can read it as `f = bz2.BZ2File(...)`. This will **not** store a significant amount of data in memory, and that's a good thing. The data will be serialized and compressed on the fly, and memory usage (minus OS caches) should not be significantly larger than a MegaByte.

Comment: @puk Nope, the `with` has no effect on the memory. As I said, it only ensures the file is actually closed. For more details, refer to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with).

Comment: This is really the same approach as mine, but with a different choice of compression and being a bit more explicit about how to write the code (and illustrating a common idiom for handling files). @phihag doesn't `bz2.BZ2File` already implement the context-management interface, the way that native files were retrofitted to do? is `contextlib.closing` really needed here?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It does, but only in Python 2.7+. I was going for 2.5+ support, since 2.6 (or even 2.5) is still the standard Python version on many systems.

Answer (score 1):

> faster, or even possible, to zip this pickle file prior to [writing]

Of course it's possible, but there's no reason to try to make an explicit zipped copy in memory (it might not fit!) before writing it, when you can *automatically cause it to be zipped as it is written, with built-in standard library functionality* ;)

See http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html . Basically, you create a special kind of stream with

```
gzip.GzipFile("output file name", "wb")
```

and then use it exactly like an ordinary `file` created with `open(...)` (or `file(...)` for that matter).

Comment: I think that is what I will be looking to do, basically zip it as it is being written

Answer (score 1):

I'd just expand on phihag's answer.

When trying to serialize an object approaching the size of RAM, **pickle/cPickle should be avoided**, since it [requires additional memory of 1-2 times the size of the object](http://www.shocksolution.com/2010/01/storing-large-numpy-arrays-on-disk-python-pickle-vs-hdf5adsf/) in order to serialize.  That's true even when streaming it to BZ2File. In my case I was even running out of swap space.

But the problem with JSON (and similarly with HDF files as mentioned in the linked article) is that it cannot serialize tuples, which in my data are used as keys to dicts. There is no great solution for this; the best I could find was to convert tuples to strings, which requires some memory of its own, but much less than pickle. Nowadays, you can also use [the ujson library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson), which is much faster than the json library.

For tuples composed of strings (requires strings to contain no commas):

```
import ujson as json
from bz2 import BZ2File

bigdata = { ('a','b','c') : 25, ('d','e') : 13 }
bigdata = dict([(','.join(k), v) for k, v in bigdata.viewitems()]) 

f = BZ2File('filename.json.bz2',mode='wb')
json.dump(bigdata,f)
f.close()
```

To re-compose the tuples:

```
bigdata = dict([(tuple(k.split(',')),v) for k,v in bigdata.viewitems()])
```

Alternatively if e.g. your keys are 2-tuples of integers:

```
bigdata2 = { (1,2): 1.2, (2,3): 3.4}
bigdata2 = dict([('%d,%d' % k, v) for k, v in bigdata2.viewitems()])
# ... save, load ...
bigdata2 = dict([(tuple(map(int,k.split(','))),v) for k,v in bigdata2.viewitems()])
```

Another advantage of this approach over pickle is that json appears to compress a significantly better than pickles when using bzip2 compression.

Answer (score -1):

Look at Google's [ProtoBuffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/techniques.html#large-data). Although they are not designed for large files out-of-the box, like audio-video files, they do well with object serialization as in your case, because they were designed for it. Practice shows that some day you may need to update structure of your files, and ProtoBuffers will handle it. Also, they are highly optimized for compression and speed. And you're not tied to Python, Java and C++ are well supported.