# Write list of tuples to txt file

Tags: python, list, tuples

Consider this list of tuples:

```
list=[((0.0, 0.0), (0.00249999994412065, -509.707885742188), (0.00499999988824129, -1017.52648925781), (0.0087500000372529, -1778.51281738281), (0.0143750002607703, -2918.21899414063), (0.0228125005960464, -4609.91650390625))]
```

I'd like to write the information to a txt file in this format:

```
0.0 0.0
0.00249999994412065 -509.707885742188
....
```

I've been using this code:

```
with open(fname, 'w') as graphd:
    for row in list:
        print >>graphd, ', '.join(map(str, row))
graphd.close()
```

where:
`fname` is the path to the file
`list` is the list of tuples

This results in: (which is close but still not what I want...)

```
(0.0, 0.0), (0.00249999994412065, -509.707885742188), (0.00499999988824129, -1017.52648925781), (0.0087500000372529, -1778.51281738281), (0.0143750002607703, -2918.21899414063), (0.0228125005960464, -4609.91650390625), (0.0328124985098839, -6560.962890625), (0.0428125001490116, -8467.638671875), (0.0528125017881393, -10321.19140625), (0.0628124997019768, -12137.498046875), (0.0728124976158142, -13877.9580078125), (0.0828125029802322, -15571.837890625), (0.0928125008940697, -17186.35546875), (0.102812498807907, -18728.310546875), (0.112812496721745, -20191.1640625), (0.122812502086163, -21548.513671875), (0.1328125, -22796.673828125), (0.142812505364418, -23935.923828125), (0.152812495827675, -24970.046875), (0.162812501192093, -25903.265625), (0.172812506556511, -26744.365234375), (0.182812497019768, -27502.3125), (0.192812502384186, -28186.765625), (0.202812492847443, -28805.953125), (0.212812498211861, -29367.408203125), (0.222812503576279, -29877.845703125), (0.232812494039536, -30343.181640625), (0.242812499403954, -30768.73046875), (0.252812504768372, -31159.8515625), (0.262812495231628, -31519.955078125), (0.272812485694885, -31852.59765625), (0.282812505960464, -32160.71875), (0.292812496423721, -32446.474609375), (0.302812486886978, -32712.138671875), (0.312812507152557, -32959.703125), (0.322812497615814, -33190.91015625), (0.332812488079071, -33407.29296875), (0.34281250834465, -33610.2109375), (0.352812498807907, -33800.859375), (0.362812489271164, -33980.30078125), (0.372812509536743, -34149.484375), (0.3828125, -34309.25390625), (0.392812490463257, -34460.3671875), (0.402812510728836, -34603.5), (0.412812501192093, -34739.26171875), (0.42281249165535, -34868.20703125), (0.432812511920929, -34990.828125), (0.442812502384186, -35107.5703125), (0.452812492847443, -35218.8515625), (0.462812513113022, -35325.04296875), (0.472812503576279, -35426.48828125), (0.482812494039536, -35523.48828125), (0.492812514305115, -35616.33203125), (0.502812504768372, -35705.28515625), (0.512812495231628, -35790.578125), (0.522812485694885, -35872.4375), (0.532812476158142, -35951.0625), (0.542812526226044, -36026.640625), (0.552812516689301, -36099.3515625), (0.562812507152557, -36169.34765625), (0.572812497615814, -36236.77734375), (0.582812488079071, -36301.78515625), (0.592812478542328, -36364.49609375), (0.602812528610229, -36425.02734375), (0.612812519073486, -36483.4921875), (0.622812509536743, -36539.9921875), (0.6328125, -36594.62890625), (0.642812490463257, -36647.4921875), (0.652812480926514, -36698.6640625), (0.662812471389771, -36748.22265625), (0.672812521457672, -36796.25), (0.682812511920929, -36842.8125), (0.692812502384186, -36887.97265625), (0.702812492847443, -36931.796875), (0.712812483310699, -36974.33984375), (0.722812473773956, -37015.66015625), (0.732812523841858, -37055.8125), (0.742812514305115, -37094.83984375), (0.752812504768372, -37132.7890625), (0.762812495231628, -37169.70703125), (0.772812485694885, -37205.6328125), (0.782812476158142, -37240.609375), (0.792812526226044, -37274.671875), (0.802812516689301, -37307.85546875), (0.812812507152557, -37340.19140625), (0.822812497615814, -37371.71875), (0.832812488079071, -37402.45703125), (0.842812478542328, -37432.4453125), (0.852812528610229, -37461.703125), (0.862812519073486, -37490.26171875), (0.872812509536743, -37518.14453125), (0.8828125, -37545.375), (0.892812490463257, -37571.98046875), (0.902812480926514, -37597.97265625), (0.912812471389771, -37623.37890625), (0.922812521457672, -37648.21875), (0.932812511920929, -37672.51171875), (0.942812502384186, -37696.26953125), (0.952812492847443, -37719.515625), (0.962812483310699, -37742.26171875), (0.972812473773956, -37764.53125), (0.982812523841858, -37786.33203125), (0.992812514305115, -37807.6796875), (1.00281250476837, -37828.58984375), (1.01281249523163, -37849.078125), (1.02281248569489, -37869.15625), (1.03281247615814, -37888.83203125), (1.0428124666214, -37908.12109375), (1.05281245708466, -37927.03515625), (1.06281244754791, -37945.58203125), (1.07281255722046, -37963.7734375), (1.08281254768372, -37981.62109375), (1.09281253814697, -37999.1328125), (1.10281252861023, -38016.3203125), (1.11281251907349, -38033.1875), (1.12281250953674, -38049.75), (1.1328125, -38081.30859375), (1.14281249046326, -38117.46484375), (1.15281248092651, -38152.9765625), (1.16281247138977, -38205.91015625), (1.17281246185303, -38262.1171875), (1.18281245231628, -38317.31640625), (1.19281244277954, -38371.5546875), (1.20281255245209, -38438.77734375), (1.21281254291534, -38511.60546875), (1.2228125333786, -38595.37109375), (1.23281252384186, -38688.0703125), (1.24281251430511, -38779.234375), (1.25281250476837, -38868.90625), (1.26281249523163, -38957.11328125), (1.27281248569489, -39043.90234375), (1.28281247615814, -39129.30078125), (1.2928124666214, -39213.34375), (1.30281245708466, -39296.0625), (1.31281244754791, -39377.48828125), (1.32281255722046, -39457.6484375), (1.33281254768372, -39536.578125), (1.34281253814697, -39614.30078125), (1.35281252861023, -39690.84375), (1.36281251907349, -39766.23828125), (1.37281250953674, -39840.5078125), (1.3828125, -39913.67578125), (1.39281249046326, -39985.765625), (1.40281248092651, -40056.8046875), (1.41281247138977, -40126.8125), (1.42281246185303, -40195.81640625), (1.43281245231628, -40263.828125), (1.44281244277954, -40330.87890625), (1.45281255245209, -40396.98046875), (1.46281254291534, -40462.16015625), (1.4728125333786, -40526.43359375), (1.48281252384186, -40589.8203125), (1.49281251430511, -40652.3359375), (1.50281250476837, -40714.00390625), (1.51281249523163, -40774.83203125), (1.52281248569489, -40835.77734375), (1.53281247615814, -40903.80078125), (1.5428124666214, -40970.921875), (1.55281245708466, -41037.16015625), (1.56281244754791, -41104.97265625), (1.57281255722046, -41179.66796875), (1.58281254768372, -41268.05859375), (1.59281253814697, -41356.78515625), (1.60281252861023, -41444.3828125), (1.61281251907349, -41530.87890625), (1.62281250953674, -41623.875), (1.6328125, -41731.9765625), (1.64281249046326, -41841.390625), (1.65281248092651, -41949.47265625), (1.66281247138977, -42056.23828125), (1.67281246185303, -42161.71875), (1.68281245231628, -42265.93359375), (1.69281244277954, -42368.90234375), (1.70281255245209, -42473.17578125), (1.71281254291534, -42581.99609375), (1.7228125333786, -42689.55078125), (1.73281252384186, -42800.32421875), (1.74281251430511, -42912.33984375), (1.75281250476837, -43023.0546875), (1.76281249523163, -43132.5), (1.77281248569489, -43242.2890625), (1.78281247615814, -43356.40625), (1.7928124666214, -43469.234375), (1.80281245708466, -43580.78515625), (1.81281244754791, -43691.0625), (1.82281255722046, -43800.109375), (1.83281254768372, -43907.953125), (1.84281253814697, -44014.60546875), (1.85281252861023, -44120.09375), (1.86281251907349, -44224.4296875), (1.87281250953674, -44327.640625), (1.8828125, -44432.32421875), (1.89281249046326, -44538.984375), (1.90281248092651, -44646.5625), (1.90531253814697, -44674.09375), (1.90625, -44689.54296875), (1.90660154819489, -44698.22265625), (1.90673339366913, -44703.1015625), (1.90674579143524, -44703.35546875), (1.90676426887512, -44703.7421875), (1.90679216384888, -44704.3203125), (1.90683376789093, -44705.1875), (1.90689635276794, -44706.76171875)
```

Comment: don't use `list` name.. .it's a reserved keyword!!

Comment: @namit: it is not a reserved keyword. It is the name of a built-in type, so using `list` masks that type. Not a great idea, but a reserved keyword would lead to a syntax error. 'except' or 'if' are reserved keywords.

Comment: There is no need to explicitly close `graphd`. Using it as a context manager with `with` makes sure it is closed for you, automatically. The `graphd.close()` line is entirely redundant.

Comment: @namit: I just used list as a bad example. In my code it has a funny name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you're iterating over the list but the list contains only one item, that is a tuple of tuples. So you must iterate over that tuple of tuples i.e `lis[0]`

```
lis=[((0.0, 0.0), (0.00249999994412065, -509.707885742188), (0.00499999988824129, -1017.52648925781), (0.0087500000372529, -1778.51281738281), (0.0143750002607703, -2918.21899414063), (0.0228125005960464, -4609.91650390625), (0.0328124985098839, -6560.962890625), (0.0428125001490116, -8467.638671875), (0.0528125017881393, -10321.19140625), (0.0628124997019768, -12137.498046875), (0.0728124976158142, -13877.9580078125), (0.0828125029802322, -15571.837890625), (0.0928125008940697, -17186.35546875), (0.102812498807907, -18728.310546875), (0.112812496721745, -20191.1640625), (0.122812502086163, -21548.513671875), (0.1328125, -22796.673828125), (0.142812505364418, -23935.923828125), (0.152812495827675, -24970.046875), (0.162812501192093, -25903.265625), (0.172812506556511, -26744.365234375), (0.182812497019768, -27502.3125), (0.192812502384186, -28186.765625), (0.202812492847443, -28805.953125), (0.212812498211861, -29367.408203125), (0.222812503576279, -29877.845703125), (0.232812494039536, -30343.181640625), (0.242812499403954, -30768.73046875), (0.252812504768372, -31159.8515625), (0.262812495231628, -31519.955078125), (0.272812485694885, -31852.59765625), (0.282812505960464, -32160.71875), (0.292812496423721, -32446.474609375), (0.302812486886978, -32712.138671875), (0.312812507152557, -32959.703125), (0.322812497615814, -33190.91015625), (0.332812488079071, -33407.29296875), (0.34281250834465, -33610.2109375), (0.352812498807907, -33800.859375), (0.362812489271164, -33980.30078125), (0.372812509536743, -34149.484375), (0.3828125, -34309.25390625), (0.392812490463257, -34460.3671875), (0.402812510728836, -34603.5), (0.412812501192093, -34739.26171875), (0.42281249165535, -34868.20703125), (0.432812511920929, -34990.828125), (0.442812502384186, -35107.5703125), (0.452812492847443, -35218.8515625), (0.462812513113022, -35325.04296875), (0.472812503576279, -35426.48828125), (0.482812494039536, -35523.48828125), (0.492812514305115, -35616.33203125), (0.502812504768372, -35705.28515625), (0.512812495231628, -35790.578125), (0.522812485694885, -35872.4375), (0.532812476158142, -35951.0625), (0.542812526226044, -36026.640625), (0.552812516689301, -36099.3515625), (0.562812507152557, -36169.34765625), (0.572812497615814, -36236.77734375), (0.582812488079071, -36301.78515625), (0.592812478542328, -36364.49609375), (0.602812528610229, -36425.02734375), (0.612812519073486, -36483.4921875), (0.622812509536743, -36539.9921875), (0.6328125, -36594.62890625), (0.642812490463257, -36647.4921875), (0.652812480926514, -36698.6640625), (0.662812471389771, -36748.22265625), (0.672812521457672, -36796.25), (0.682812511920929, -36842.8125), (0.692812502384186, -36887.97265625), (0.702812492847443, -36931.796875), (0.712812483310699, -36974.33984375), (0.722812473773956, -37015.66015625), (0.732812523841858, -37055.8125), (0.742812514305115, -37094.83984375), (0.752812504768372, -37132.7890625), (0.762812495231628, -37169.70703125), (0.772812485694885, -37205.6328125), (0.782812476158142, -37240.609375), (0.792812526226044, -37274.671875), (0.802812516689301, -37307.85546875), (0.812812507152557, -37340.19140625), (0.822812497615814, -37371.71875), (0.832812488079071, -37402.45703125), (0.842812478542328, -37432.4453125), (0.852812528610229, -37461.703125), (0.862812519073486, -37490.26171875), (0.872812509536743, -37518.14453125), (0.8828125, -37545.375), (0.892812490463257, -37571.98046875), (0.902812480926514, -37597.97265625), (0.912812471389771, -37623.37890625), (0.922812521457672, -37648.21875), (0.932812511920929, -37672.51171875), (0.942812502384186, -37696.26953125), (0.952812492847443, -37719.515625), (0.962812483310699, -37742.26171875), (0.972812473773956, -37764.53125), (0.982812523841858, -37786.33203125), (0.992812514305115, -37807.6796875), (1.00281250476837, -37828.58984375), (1.01281249523163, -37849.078125), (1.02281248569489, -37869.15625), (1.03281247615814, -37888.83203125), (1.0428124666214, -37908.12109375), (1.05281245708466, -37927.03515625), (1.06281244754791, -37945.58203125), (1.07281255722046, -37963.7734375), (1.08281254768372, -37981.62109375), (1.09281253814697, -37999.1328125), (1.10281252861023, -38016.3203125), (1.11281251907349, -38033.1875), (1.12281250953674, -38049.75), (1.1328125, -38081.30859375), (1.14281249046326, -38117.46484375), (1.15281248092651, -38152.9765625), (1.16281247138977, -38205.91015625), (1.17281246185303, -38262.1171875), (1.18281245231628, -38317.31640625), (1.19281244277954, -38371.5546875), (1.20281255245209, -38438.77734375), (1.21281254291534, -38511.60546875), (1.2228125333786, -38595.37109375), (1.23281252384186, -38688.0703125), (1.24281251430511, -38779.234375), (1.25281250476837, -38868.90625), (1.26281249523163, -38957.11328125), (1.27281248569489, -39043.90234375), (1.28281247615814, -39129.30078125), (1.2928124666214, -39213.34375), (1.30281245708466, -39296.0625), (1.31281244754791, -39377.48828125), (1.32281255722046, -39457.6484375), (1.33281254768372, -39536.578125), (1.34281253814697, -39614.30078125), (1.35281252861023, -39690.84375), (1.36281251907349, -39766.23828125), (1.37281250953674, -39840.5078125), (1.3828125, -39913.67578125), (1.39281249046326, -39985.765625), (1.40281248092651, -40056.8046875), (1.41281247138977, -40126.8125), (1.42281246185303, -40195.81640625), (1.43281245231628, -40263.828125), (1.44281244277954, -40330.87890625), (1.45281255245209, -40396.98046875), (1.46281254291534, -40462.16015625), (1.4728125333786, -40526.43359375), (1.48281252384186, -40589.8203125), (1.49281251430511, -40652.3359375), (1.50281250476837, -40714.00390625), (1.51281249523163, -40774.83203125), (1.52281248569489, -40835.77734375), (1.53281247615814, -40903.80078125), (1.5428124666214, -40970.921875), (1.55281245708466, -41037.16015625), (1.56281244754791, -41104.97265625), (1.57281255722046, -41179.66796875), (1.58281254768372, -41268.05859375), (1.59281253814697, -41356.78515625), (1.60281252861023, -41444.3828125), (1.61281251907349, -41530.87890625), (1.62281250953674, -41623.875), (1.6328125, -41731.9765625), (1.64281249046326, -41841.390625), (1.65281248092651, -41949.47265625), (1.66281247138977, -42056.23828125), (1.67281246185303, -42161.71875), (1.68281245231628, -42265.93359375), (1.69281244277954, -42368.90234375), (1.70281255245209, -42473.17578125), (1.71281254291534, -42581.99609375), (1.7228125333786, -42689.55078125), (1.73281252384186, -42800.32421875), (1.74281251430511, -42912.33984375), (1.75281250476837, -43023.0546875), (1.76281249523163, -43132.5), (1.77281248569489, -43242.2890625), (1.78281247615814, -43356.40625), (1.7928124666214, -43469.234375), (1.80281245708466, -43580.78515625), (1.81281244754791, -43691.0625), (1.82281255722046, -43800.109375), (1.83281254768372, -43907.953125), (1.84281253814697, -44014.60546875), (1.85281252861023, -44120.09375), (1.86281251907349, -44224.4296875), (1.87281250953674, -44327.640625), (1.8828125, -44432.32421875), (1.89281249046326, -44538.984375), (1.90281248092651, -44646.5625), (1.90531253814697, -44674.09375), (1.90625, -44689.54296875), (1.90660154819489, -44698.22265625), (1.90673339366913, -44703.1015625), (1.90674579143524, -44703.35546875), (1.90676426887512, -44703.7421875), (1.90679216384888, -44704.3203125), (1.90683376789093, -44705.1875), (1.90689635276794, -44706.76171875))]
with open("abc","w") as f:
    for line in lis[0]:
        strs=" ".join(str(x) for x in line)
        f.write(strs+"\n")
```

output (abc's content):

```
0.0 0.0
0.00249999994412 -509.707885742
0.00499999988824 -1017.52648926
0.00875000003725 -1778.51281738
0.0143750002608 -2918.21899414
.....
```

Comment: @jpcgandre this takes only 1.57 ms on my system.

Comment: @jpcgandre this may be helpful :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641592/fastest-way-to-store-large-files-in-python

Answer (score 2):

I would store the data as [JSON](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). This makes it easy to export and import the data again using Python. Which makes it easy to share the data with other languages, or programs.

```
import json
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
  json.dump(list, outfile)
```

You can then load the data again using [json.load](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load).

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as infile:
  print json.load(infile)
```

If you need more readable data you can add indent=4 to json.dump.

```
json.dump(list, outfile, indent=4)
```

The output would be

```
[
    [
        [
            0.0, 
            0.0
        ], 
        [
            0.00249999994412065, 
            -509.707885742188
        ], 
        [
            0.00499999988824129, 
            -1017.52648925781
        ], 
        ....
```

Comment: Is this faster than the other methods? And can I open json with nodepad of alike?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is faster, but if you need to import the code again this is without doubt the easiest way. You could simply do `list = json.load(infile)` to load the data again as a list. No need for tides for loops. And yes you can still open it in notepad.

Comment: JSON is widely portable.  The specification is very simple so it is easy to implement correctly.  If you use JSON to save your file, you can then import the file into Python, JavaScript, Ruby, Perl, C#, C++, etc. very easily.  JSON makes a plain text file, so yes you can open it with Notepad... you might want to use WordPad if you write a JSON file on Linux as the line-endings are not quite the same as in Windows, and Notepad doesn't deal with it.  I'm pretty sure the built-in JSON support in Python is written in C, so yes it will be faster.

Comment: Thanks @steveha. Perfect complimentary comment to my answer. :)

Comment: @eandersson: It is fast. But the result is: `[[[0.0, 0.0], [0.00249999994412065, -509.707885742188],...`

Comment: That is because json uses a slightly different format. If you import it again it should be in the exact same format list/tuples.

Comment: btw try changing `json.dump` to `json.dump(list, outfile, indent=4)` for better readability.

Comment: @eandersson: The problem is that then I need to work with the file in Excel or other program. If I have the data in the file structured like:
`0.0 0.0` \n
`a b`
it is alot easier to export to those programs.

Comment: You can import json into Excel, there are a bunch of tutorials on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch first and second elements in `row` and join with `\n`:

```
with open(fname, 'w') as graphd:
    for row in list:
        print >>graphd, '\n'.join(map(str, row[0])).join(" ").join(map(str, row[0]))
graphd.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the list, so create tuple of tuples like this

```
my_data = (3123, 123123), (133232, 1231232)
for row in my_data:
    handler.write(' '.join(str(r) for r in row) + "\n")
```