# how to write list of tuples into new file using python

Tags: python

```
my_list=[('127.0.0.1', '-', '-', '06/Apr/2017:00:00:00 -0400', 
          'POST /Apps/js_recommanded_jobs.php HTTP/1.1',
          '200', '20546', '-', '-'),
         ('127.0.0.1', '-', '-', '06/Apr/2017:00:00:00 -0400',
         'POST /Apps/auto_suggestion_solr.php HTTP/1.1', 
         '200', '185', '-', '-')]
```

I need output as like below:

```
('127.0.0.1', '-', '-', '06/Apr/2017:00:00:00 -0400', 'POST /Apps/js_recommanded_jobs.php HTTP/1.1', '200', '20546', '-', '-'),
('127.0.0.1', '-', '-', '06/Apr/2017:00:00:00 -0400', 'POST /Apps/auto_suggestion_solr.php HTTP/1.1', '200', '185', '-', '-')
```

Comment: please some one help me with this

Comment: which format u want to write file? means CSV?

Comment: No i want to write in text file format

Comment: this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344009/write-list-of-tuples-to-txt-file

Answer (score 1):

If you need to save it as the String, you may do the following.

- Open a file in write mode, named as sample_file.txt
- Map every element of my_list to String
- Writing every tuple separated by delimiter ',\n' to sample_file.txt

  ```
  with open('sample_file.txt', 'wb') as new_file:
      new_list = map(str, my_list)
      new_file.write(",\n".join(new_list))
  ```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open File in write mode.
2. Iterate every row from input list.
3. Write row into file and add new line init.
4. Close file.

**Demo:**

```
>>> fp = open("myfile.txt", "w")
>>> for row in my_list:
...     fp.write(str(row) + "\n")
... 
>>> fp.close()
>>>
```

Edit 2:
Remove unnecessary comma at the end by using map and string join method.

**Demo:**

```
>>> fp = open("myfile.txt", "w")
>>> fp.write(",\n".join(map(str, my_list)))
>>> fp.close()
```

Comment: I think, it's mode instead of mood! ;)

Comment: This will an unnecessary comma at the end of the file! How is it a solution to this question?

Comment: @abhinav: Thank for suggestion, did changes. :)

Comment: @VivekSable It's interesting the way you've shorter the code by using map function! Nice one!

Comment: I know this isn't codegolf but for safety you could change `fp = open("myfile.txt", "w")` to `with open("myfile.txt", "w") as fp:` for safety as you don't need to remember to `.close()` it

Answer (score 0):

This code works.

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in my_list:
        f.write(str(line)+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job.

```
with open('mylist.txt', 'w') as f:
    my_list = [('a','b'),('b','c')]
    listtocopy = ',\n'.join(str(x) for x in my_list)
    f.write(listtocopy)
    f.close()
```